# How to convert existing Android application made with PhoneGap in Eclipse to iPhone?

Tags: android, iphone, deployment, cordova

I've created one Demo Android Application in Eclipse Indigo using PhoneGap. Now I want to deploy the same application to iPhone platform. Is it possible? Or I've to start it from the scratch for iPhone also?

Any suggestions or tricks are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Mac, you can simply start a new PhoneGap project in Xcode and import the www folder. This method works only if you used HTML,CSS and non-device-specific Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut. You need to start from the scratch for iPhone.

Comment: Well, I dont think so. Isn't there any other tool for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Some application you cannot convert into iPhone. You have to code the whole project again.

Comment: Well, my whole application solely comprises JavaScript,HTML and CSS only.

Comment: yah I understood that u did in phonegap right? but apple does not allow. I also tried one month back. but no result came in my pocket.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at this moment. This kind of solution is not available.

Answer (score 0):

That's true that there is no direct way to do it. But it wasn't as bad as start from scratch. You will find the more complex your Android project gets the more complex your import will be. So you better start early and as the project move along you add more things on both sides. Most of your code will able to share on both platform but the plugin and device specific functions will give you surprise from time to time. Pay more attention on the plugin they are the real tricky sometimes.

What I do now is I have my Android code checked in after all the test done and released. (I work on PC with Android and Mac on iOS) get the released code and checkout on my Mac. I setup a PhoneGap in xCode (follow this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) And then backup the "www" folder of the project. and then I copy the "www" from the Android project. You may need to work on your index.html and index.js a little bit in order to get it working. The Initial Process and OnDeviceReady is a bit different between Android and iOS. after that if you didn't use any plugins, you should able to run your app on simulator.

I wish you good luck and here is and youtube about this topic it helps me understand. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcES5nIbMkk